# How to add a message with timeout after ajax success (or error) in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How do I add an update message with timeout after ajax success / error in knockout.js?

**I can do it like this:**

```
var ViewModel = {
    var self = this;
    self.message = ko.observable("");
    self.setMessage = function(message, timeout){
        self.message(message);
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.message("");
        }, timeout);
    }
    .....
    $.ajax(url, {
        success: function(obj){
            self.setMessage(obj.message, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<span data-bind='text: message()'></span>
```

But I have a lot of ViewModels with ajax calls in my web app and I want to be able to do this in every ViewModel, and I don't like to copy paste my code.

**I need help in extending knockout so that I can add a single method and just import it to all my view models.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [ajgiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1088705/ajgiv) I was able to use the above link to come up with the solution. If I was the only one working on the web app and if there are lesser number of view models I would have gone with the above mentioned approach. (I have a knockout.ext.js class that contains all the extenders needed for the app)

So I added this function to my knockout.ext.js:

```
ko.timeoutMessageModel = function(initialMessage){
    var self = this;
    self.message = ko.observable(initialMessage);
    self.setTimeout = function(msg, time) {
        self.message(msg);
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.message("");
        }, time);
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
var message = ko.timeoutMessageModel("initialMessage");
$.ajax(url, 
    success: function(data){
        self.message.setTimeout(data.message, 1000);
    }
);
```

... and so on in all my view models!

**HTML:**

```
<data-bind="text: message.message()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you create a base VM that is inherited by the other VMs, and create an ajax function that other VM's can call.

check this out :

[Accessing viewModel functions by prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834823/accessing-viewmodel-functions-by-prototype)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It almost did the trick for me. The thing is there are already a lof of view models and I'm not the only one working on them so I can go back and change all the VMs to inherit a base model. I took the link you shared and added an extender method which did the trick!